# Stripe, what webhook event is called at subscription's end?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events, stripe-payments

Not when the customer cancels, but when the actual last moment their subscription has been paid for.

I'm looking [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#events), but can't quite find a clear description of that case. I'm writing a handler in asp.net mvc/C# and have everything ready minus which event to catch.

Answer (score 0):

Either `charge.succeeded` or `invoice.payment_succeeded` will be what you want. Which one is a matter of what makes the most sense to you and your use case.

`charge.succeeded` will be posted for *any* charge which succeeds; `invoice.payment_succeeded` will be posted only for invoices. An invoice successfully being paid will trigger them in that order (though you may not receive them in that order).

Remember that an invoice does not necessarily imply a subscription—depending how you're handling billing, you may want to verify there's a subscription included in the invoice when responding to the webhook.